# BeanCurrentlyInCreationException Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jetty

How I can fix this exception?

Without Spring Boot everything works.

So problem is in "App" section, am I right?

Caught exception

```
BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pooledConnectionFactory': 
Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

App

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ImportResource("classpath:contexts/bean-locations.xml")
public class MyApp{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new SpringApplication(MyApp.class).run(args);
}
}
```

Bean usage via import

```
<import resource="classpath*:contexts/database/datasource/base-data-source.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath*:contexts/database/datasource/pooled-data-source.xml"/>
```

First file from import:

```
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd">
<bean id="baseDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${connection.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${connection.userName}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${connection.password}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${connection.url}"/>
</bean>
```

Second file from import:

```
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd">
<bean id="pool" class="org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool">
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis"><value>300000</value></property>
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis"><value>60000</value></property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSourceConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.DataSourceConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg><ref bean="baseDataSource"/></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="pooledConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg index="0"><ref bean="dataSourceConnectionFactory"/></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="1"><ref bean="pool"/></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="2"><null/></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="3"><null/></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="4"><value>false</value></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="5"><value>true</value></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource"
      depends-on="pooledConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg><ref bean="pool"/></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Boot has [Database initialization](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html) feature which conflicts with your `DataSource` config. See `DataSourceInitializer` class. It tries to obtain data source before its creation.

To fix your app you can

1. Disable initializer using property

   ```
   spring.datasource.initialize=false
   ```
2. Exclude data source auto config as you have your own configuration

   ```
   @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
   ```

Comment: What is also required for Hibernate and HSQL usage with Spring Boot? Maybe something like for tests? public void beforeTestClass(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
        IDatabaseConnection databaseDataSourceConnection = new DatabaseDataSourceConnection(
                (DataSource) testContext.getApplicationContext().getBean("dataSource")
        );
        databaseDataSourceConnection.getConnection().prepareStatement(
                "SET DATABASE REFERENTIAL INTEGRITY FALSE").execute();
    }